# which server is best for me?

Tags: cloud-computing, dedicated-server

I am looking for a best hosting service for my website. My website is a PHP MySQl driven site which hase got site scrapping for more than 10 websites and near about 8-10 API pursing and some about 150 mb dat file reading(from local hard drive), and also one rss pursing,Live graph from other sites, geo map from Google,Map api from Google and so on. one widget which real-time result for any one who chose the same.

so my question is which is best option for me. actually I am considering softlayer cloud as they are pretty cheap and more facilities than rackspace. another option is a dedicated server which has 2 single core processor, 4GB ram and 250GB sata II. with 100 mbps uplink.

so please tell me which will be the best option?? I heard that dedicated server has lots of limitations than cloud. but for cloud they uses SAN for storage so I am afraid the reading proces for database may be bit slower...and their basic plan ram is only 1 GB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not about the kind of content that you are hosting, but more about the number of people whom will browse your website.
For more than a few thousand user I think you should avoid VPS and others. Dedicated servers are quite efficient, and each provider will propose different kind.